# In FCM, how can we send the push notification to the particular group of people and to single person?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making an android application in which i am using serverless FCM push notification. So, have to send two types of notification, first is a broadcast notification from a customer to all the registered shopkeepers within 1-2 km circumference of the current location of the customer, and the second one is the reply of the shopkeeper to that particular customer only. I am stuck with this code, not able to resolve the problem. My nodes.js and android code is below mentioned.

```
//import firebase functions modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// Listens for new messages added to messages/:pushId
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {

    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var valueObject = event.data.val();

    if(valueObject.photoUrl != null) {
      valueObject.photoUrl= "Sent you a photo!";
    }
console.log('Push notification 1');
  // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title:valueObject.name,
            body: valueObject.text || valueObject.photoUrl,
            sound: "default"

        },
    };
console.log('Push notification 2');
  //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24

    };

console.log('Push notification 3');
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});






public class CloudMain extends BaseActivty {



    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 10;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;


    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageRef;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cloud_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userId = user.getUid();
        mUsername = user.getDisplayName() ; //ANONYMOUS;
        mMessagesReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(userId).child("messages");
        mChatPhotosStorageRef = mStorage.getReference().child("users").child(userId).child("chat_photos");

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("pushNotifications");
        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);


        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, messages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});


        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click

                Message message = new Message(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                mMessagesReference.push().setValue(message);

                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });


        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String userId = user.getUid();
                Log.d("onAuthStateChanged: ",userId);
                if (user != null) {


                } else {

                }
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
        mMessageAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            StorageReference photoRef =
                    mChatPhotosStorageRef.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Message message = new Message(null, mUsername, downloadUrl.toString());
                            mMessagesReference.push().setValue(message);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }



    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(message);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };
            mMessagesReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }

    private void detachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener != null) {
            mMessagesReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
            mChildEventListener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi kAnwAl. This is a bit broad. Could you specifically point out where you're having a problem with?

Comment: i am not able to send notification with the above code, whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 500 error from the server? You better stringyfy the json body,

```
body: Json.stringify(**content**);
```